# PCB Layout designing

Tags: pcb-design, layout

Propagation delay is more in which topology (stripline or microstrip)???

I am having mutiple signals in a high speed board and some signal are routed too long than how can i say that board trace is radiating? What are the parameters to be taken care for these?

Comment: Try and make your question a bit clearer, it might help. In addition, try adding a picture of what you are referring to in the second part of your question. We can only answer the questions you ask, and if you ask questions poorly, we can't give good answers

Comment: Those who dont understand questions please dont simply create comments.or you can avoid to answer such questions...bro

Comment: Seeing as a lot of the names in that "unclear what you're asking" are from people who are clearly fluent in english, you might consider the possibility the problem is indeed your question, and not my or others (supposed lack off) ability to comprehend it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to first question is for a given values of Thickness(height of trace), width(width of trace) and height(distance between the reference layer and trace),

The propagation delay is more for microstrip compared to stripline.

Coming to second question, A thumb rule can be like radiation begin to appear when round trip track delays (i.e. time for a signal to do a trip in forward direction, and return) have started to exceed the rise / fall times (whichever is smaller).

Example, it is best to the limit the length of a trace carrying 2ns rise time signal (which translates to roughly 12 inch), to 2 inch. The value of 2 inch is arrived as follows:

Propagation delay of signals is 1ns time for 6 inch.
In 2ns time (the given rise time), it propagates 12 inch.
Half of this length is 6 inch, and 1/6th is 2 inch. Hence for a fail safe design, it is best to limit the track length to 2 inch.
The following table shows how it becomes necessary to keep track lengths far smaller as rise / fall times decreases:

[image]

sources:
http://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-094.pdf
https://www.quora.com/At-what-clock-frequency-do-PCB-layout-engineers-need-to-start-considering-high-speed-digital-design-issues

Comment: Thanks Pavan, We also consider same parameters for Stripline also than how it is more with microstrip ??? Can you explore your ideas?

Comment: Please follow equation 6 and equation 10 of the pdf shared in answer. The reason for the different speeds is that stripline is covered by dielectric on both sides and have two reference planes.

Answer (score 0):

many parameter may be impact, such as:

Trace Thickness,Substrate Height,Trace Width,Substrate Dielectric
to find more see here: [microstrip-impedance-calculator](https://www.eeweb.com/tools/microstrip-impedance)